# Serverless Shared API Gateway Error when deploying to different stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, api-gateway

I'm using serverless version 1.29.2

I have a created an initial cloudformation script that creates an API GateWay REST API that will be used by other services. So Here is the cloudformation script responsible for it.

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"API",
   "Resources":{
      "APIGw":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
         "Properties":{
            "Name":"API-GW"
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "ApiGwRestApiId":{
         "Value":{
            "Ref":"APIGw"
         },
         "Export":{
            "Name":"apigw-restApiId"
         }
      },
      "eyesApiGwRestApiRootResourceId":{
         "Value":{
            "Fn::GetAtt":[
               "APIGw",
               "RootResourceId"
            ]
         },
         "Export":{
            "Name":"apigw-rootResourceId"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is serverless.yml for the application I was trying to deploy.

```
service: template-test-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: eu-central-1
  stage: ${self:custom.environment.stage}
  environment:
    stage: ${self:custom.environment.stage}
  apiGateway:
    restApiId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': apigw-restApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      'Fn::ImportValue': apigw-rootResourceId
```

When I perform an `sls deploy --stage dev` everything works fine, However when I perform another deploy to `sls deploy --stage prod`

This error shows up.

```
Another resource with the same parent already has this name
```

Answer (score 10):

I've struggled with this one for a week now and the issue is to do with the way API Gateway is constructred out of resources and methods. From the documentation

> In Amazon API Gateway, you build a REST API as a collection of programmable entities known as API Gateway resources. For example, you use a RestApi resource to represent an API that can contain a collection of Resource entities. Each Resource entity can in turn have one or more Method resources. Expressed in the request parameters and body, a Method defines the application programming interface for the client to access the exposed Resource and represents an incoming request submitted by the client.

Serverless CLI creates all the resource/methods for you when you have a function trigged by an http event.

```
functions:
  GetScenesInGame:
    handler: handler.hello
    layers: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:layer:pynamodb-layer:1
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: api/v1/game/{gameId}/scene
```

From the example above this creates five resources ( api, v1, game, gameIdParam, scene) and finally adds a GET method on the the final resource.

Unfortunately when you have two seperate stacks (as you might in a microservice setup) if they are any part of the above methods then it errors with **Another resource with the same parent already has this name**

The solution is highlighted in this article from serverless [deploy serverless microservice on aws](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-microservice/) although its not very explict and easily missed.

Firstly there is a top level cloudformation template which configures the required resources.

For the resource you want to add a serverless microservice to you export the id of the resource as an output variable in your stack.

Then in the serverless.yml file you import the api gateway reference and apigateway resource id.

You can then deploy each service without getting a clash of resource names in the api structure.

The templates below show having a top level set of resources.

`api/v1/game/{gameId}/page`

`api/v1/game/{gameId}/scene`

And then attaching **PageService** to the **page** resource and **SceneService** to the **scene** resource.

### api-gateway.yml

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "S3 template for deploying S3 to be used by ACS s3 connector."

Resources:
    TestApiGw:
            Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
            Properties:
                Name: !Sub 'test-apigw-throwaway'

    ApiResource:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
            ParentId: !GetAtt 
                - TestApiGw
                - RootResourceId
            PathPart: "api"

    VersionResource:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
            ParentId: !Ref ApiResource
            PathPart: "v1"

    GameResource:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
            ParentId: !Ref VersionResource
            PathPart: "game"

    GameParamResource:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
            ParentId: !Ref GameResource
            PathPart: "{gameId}"

    SceneResource:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
        Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
            ParentId: !Ref GameParamResource
            PathPart: "scene"

    PageResource:
            Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
            Properties:
                RestApiId: !Ref TestApiGw
                ParentId: !Ref GameParamResource
                PathPart: "page"

Outputs:
    ApiRestApiId:
        Value: !Ref TestApiGw
        Export:
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-TestApiId

    ApiRootResourceId:
        Value:
            Fn::GetAtt:
                - TestApiGw
                - RootResourceId
        Export:
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ApiRootResourceVar

    ApiSceneResourceVar:
        Value: !Ref SceneResource
        Export:
        # variable names are global so this will need more work to make it unique across stages.
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ApiSceneResourceVar

    ApiPageResourceVar:
        Value: !Ref PageResource
        Export:
        # variable names are global so this will need more work to make it unique across stages.
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ApiPageResourceVar
```

### serverless.yml ( Serverless Cli file for Page Service)

```
service: scrap-page-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: 
      "Fn::ImportValue": throw-stack-1-TestApiId
    restApiRootResourceId: 
      "Fn::ImportValue": throw-stack-1-ApiPageResourceVar

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: ""
          method: get
```

### serverless.yml ( Serverless Cli file for Scene Service)

```
service: scrap-scene-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: 
      "Fn::ImportValue": throw-stack-1-TestApiId
    restApiRootResourceId: 
      "Fn::ImportValue": throw-stack-1-ApiSceneResourceVar

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: ""
          method: get
```

Hopefully this helps others getting this issue and if somebody has a better way of doing it I'd be keen to know :-)

Comment: Hi @Alex Levitt, have you tried this using `serverless-domain-manager` at all?

Comment: Its been a while since I last looked at it but I recall that serverless-domain-manager was one of the solutions I attempted but it didn't seem to have the control I needed to avoid the route clash.

Comment: After searching the internet for a long time, just found this answer. Thank you!! This worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Did take a look at [Serverless documentation on sharing API Gateway](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources) ?

It seems that you have to create common resource path components are CloudFormed objects

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thanks for the edit.  Could you add event more information?  If that link goes down, this answer would be insufficient still.  Explain how to create common resource path components, and how common resource path components are CloudFormed objects.

Comment: I would appreciate an example of how to set this up.